# How do I convert date strings such as "1 September 1899" to "1899-09-01"

Tags: date, format, openrefine, grel

I want to convert strings like "1 September 1899" to "1899-09-01" ("1 July 2020" to "2020--07-01"). How do I do this?

value.toString("dd/MM/YYYY") which of course did not work
and date_parse_from_format(value,'M jS Y', $date_str) failed also

None of the answers posted worked.

Comment: I'm curious where you found the "answers posted" which didn't work. `date_parse_from_format` seems to be a PHP thing.

Answer (score 1):

In OpenRefine a value like "1 September 1899" has no further meaning. But you can transform this text to a date type using [toDate](https://openrefine.org/docs/manual/grelfunctions#todateo-b-monthfirst-s-format1-s-format2-). Then you can use certain components from the date (like year, month, ...) to form a new string using the [toString](https://openrefine.org/docs/manual/grelfunctions#tostringo-string-format-optional) function.

The following GREL expression will just do that:

```js
value.toDate("dd MMMM yyyy").toString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

You may also use multiple formats in the `toDate` function to convert a column with mixed date formats to a common format. Details on the meaning of e.g. `yyyy` can be found in the documentation for the [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class.

Comment: Neat. Thank you for this. (In the meantime, I found common transforms (of a cells in a row) which also did the trick.

Comment: As described in https://openrefine.org/docs/manual/exploring#dates the automatic detection of date formats might be error prone. But if it works for you all the better.